# Detecting jQuery Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm writing a plugin for jQuery and I want to make it so the user can pass data to the plugin in any form. I have the JSON or array problem worked out, but I'm having trouble trying to determine if the data is a jQuery object.

```
data = $('#list li');
console.debug( $.isPlainObject(data) );   // false
console.debug( $.isArray(data) );         // false
console.debug( data[0].tagName == "LI" ); // true, but see note below
```

The last method returns true, but there is no guarantee that the user is using an `LI` tag for their data, so I think I need something like this:

```
if ( $.isjQueryObject(data) ) { /* do something */ }
```

Does anyone know a better method?

Comment: Apparently, there is a Ben Alman plugin for that - http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#isjquery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `jQuery` object (or its alias `$`) is a plain [*constructor function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_Constructor_Function), all jQuery objects inherit from the `jQuery.prototype` object (or its alias `jQuery.fn`).

You can check if an object exists in the prototype chain of other object, by using either the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/instanceof_Operator) operator or the [`isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Object:isPrototypeOf) method, for example:

```
function isjQueryObject(obj) {
  return obj instanceof jQuery;
}
```

Or:

```
function isjQueryObject(obj) {
  return jQuery.fn.isPrototypeOf(obj);
}
```

Comment: Just as an update, using `instanceof` causes a memory leak in IE (http://ajaxian.com/archives/working-aroung-the-instanceof-memory-leak)

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery object is simply a collection of elements, stored as an array, with additional functions and stuff attached.  So essentially you could use the jQuery elements just like you would a regular array.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, yes I know the jQuery object is stored as an array of objects, but I'm trying to find an easy way to differentiate it from others.

Comment: Ah okay, I'd recommend trying @CMS's solution then.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var isJq = data instanceof jQuery;
```